# How do I refer to the same type variable in different type annotations?

Tags: haskell

Say I have the following:

```
import Control.Monad.Random

foo :: IO Float
foo = fmap realToFrac getRandom
```

GHC rightly complains about not knowing the type of `getRandom`; I can fix this by doing

```
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: IO Double)
```

However, consider instead the situtation where I have:

```
foo :: (Functor m, MonadRandom m) => m Float
foo = fmap realToFrac getRandom
```

I can not do only

```
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: m Double)
```

I must repeat the `MonadRandom` constraint:

```
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: MonadRandom m => m Double)
```

With a high number of constraints, this would result in a lot of extra typing. I would rather not have to do that. I am aware that I could use `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Random

foo :: MonadRandom m => m Float
foo = do
    x :: Double <- getRandom
    return (realToFrac x)
```

but this is just as verbose, and additionally I wouldn't be able to apply it in all such situations.

I am also aware of the [`PartialTypeSignatures`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures) proposal. I *think* this might allow me to do:

```
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: _ Double)
```

but it's not entirely clear from my scan over its (long) description. Unfortunately, `PartialTypeSignatures` is not ready for primetime and as such has not yet been included in a released version of GHC.

I'm obviously welcome to other suggestions, but one solution to this problem I can think of would be some way to identify `m` with `n` in the following:

```
foo :: (Functor m, MonadRandom m) => m Float
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: n Double)
```

Is this kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition was correct: `ScopedTypeVariables` is the right extension for the job:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Random

foo :: (Functor m, MonadRandom m) => m Float
foo = fmap realToFrac (getRandom :: m Double)
```

Comment: When I think about what *scoped type variables* actually means, that seems incredibly obvious. Thank you.